# Font Awesome shows up the icons as squares even after the "Pro" kit is used and the font family has been changes to "Font Awesome 5 Pro"

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am using the Font Awesome 5 Pro Kit(Webfont+CSS) in the  section of my code and have changed the css to :`font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; font-style: normal; font-weight: 900;`
However, all the icons appear as squares even after the content has been set in css using the given format: `content: '\f3c5';`

Comment: Can you post how you add FontAwesome to the page? Maybe there is a typo. Is there a console error?

Comment: did you buy  licence to use the Pro version?